# R - Passing list of dataframe name into function

Tags: r

I have dataframes and want to pass them as a parameter to process in function. Let say there are 4 dataframes and want to rename first columns to 'ROWNUM'.

```
df1 = data.frame(c(1:10),sample(1:100,10))
df2 = data.frame(c(1:10),sample(1:100,10))
df3 = data.frame(c(1:10),sample(1:100,10))
df4 = data.frame(c(1:10),sample(1:100,10))

function(df) colnames(df)[1] = 'ROWNUM'
```

My objective is I want to rename in one shot rather than passing one by one

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` after keeping the datasets in a `list`

```
nm1 <- ls(pattern="df\\d+")
lst <- lapply(mget(nm1), function(x) {
           colnames(x)[1] <- 'ROWNUM'
            x})
```

It is better to keep the datasets in a `list`, but if we need to update the original datasets

```
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or we use `assign`

```
for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
 assign(nm1[j], `names<-`(get(nm1[j]),
            c("ROWNUM", names(get(nm1[j]))[-1])))
 }
```